# Can OpenVX be used for OpenCV functions?

Tags: computer-vision, hardware-acceleration, opencv, openvx, python

Can one use all OpenCV libraries in OpenVX.Or only we can use the OpenVX that are defined in their sample implementation?

Comment: I also have this question about interaction/equivalence of openvx and opencv